# Snippets VS Code Regex

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code, code-snippets

I need your help, I am building a snippets, but I need to transform the path of the file which is this:

```
D:\Project\test\src\EnsLib\File\aaa\bbb
```

and I need it to be like this:

```
EnsLib\File\aaa\bbb
```

just leave me from "SRC" forward and replace the \ with points.

```
Example: D:\Project\test\src\EnsLib\File\aaa\bbb

Result: EnsLib.File.aaa.bbb
```

that always after the src folder is the starting point

my test regex are these:

```
"${TM_DIRECTORY/(.*\\\\{4})/$1/}",
"${TM_DIRECTORY/.*src\\\\(.*)\\\\(.*)$/.$2/}.${TM_FILENAME_BASE}",
// "${TM_DIRECTORY/.*\\\\(.*)\\\\(.*)$/$1.$2/}.${TM_FILENAME_BASE}",
// "${RELATIVE_FILEPATH/\\D{4}(\\W)\\..+$/$1/g}",
// "${TM_DIRECTORY/(.*src\\\\)//g}.${TM_FILENAME_BASE}",
// "${RELATIVE_FILEPATH/(\\D{3})\\W|(\\..+$)/$1.$2/g}",
// "${RELATIVE_FILEPATH/\\W/./g}",
```

Comment: Do you want to say `bbb` is the file name here? Well, try ``"${TM_FILEPATH/^.*?\\\\src\\\\|(\\\\)/${1:+.}/g}"``

Comment: thanks. but bbb is a folder. I just need the folders. If you could help me with that, I would appreciate it

Comment: Aha, so try ``"${TM_DIRECTORY/^.*?\\\\src\\\\|(\\\\)/${1:+.}/g}"``

Comment: How does `\\\\` work? Where did you find the docs for that? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you want

```
"${TM_DIRECTORY/^.*?\\\\src\\\\|(\\\\)/${1:+.}/g}"
```

The regex is `^.*?\\src\\|(\\)`, it matches

- `^` - start of string
- `.*?` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `\\src\\` - `\src\` string
- `|` - or
- `(\\)` - Group 1 (`$1`): a `\` char.

If Group 1 matches, the replacement is a `.`, else, the replacement is an empty string, i.e. the text from the start of string till `\src\` is simply removed.